# Iterate through sheets with for loop incrementing

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am new to VBA and having some trouble with my code. I have sheets named 2001, 2002, 2003... 2010. I want to pick each of these sheets in turn and perform some simple operations on each worksheet. I have tried to use a for loop, incrementing from 2000 to 2010 but it is getting stuck. I think the problem is I don't know how to specify the sheet name that it should pick using the for loop.

```
Sub Compile_data_from_worksheets()

Dim i As Integer   ' declare i as integer, this will count the number of Manufacturers
Dim y As Long      ' declare y as long, this will capture the number of rows in a worksheet
Dim x As String    ' declare x as string, this will capture the name of each Manufacturer

Application.StatusBar = "running macro"    ' places message on the statusbar while macro runs

ThisWorkbook.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    'stop the screen updating as the macro runs
Application.CutCopyMode = False       'clears the clipboard


For i = 2000 To 2002              ' for each of the years in turn

Sheets(i).Select          ' activate worksheet 2000
Range("A17").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Combined_data").Activate

y = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count        'count how many rows of worksheet "AllData_Raw" have been used so far.

Cells(y + 1, 1).Select          'use the Cells command to select data and then paste selection

ActiveSheet.Paste

Next i                          ' next year...

End Sub
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that if an integer is placed inside the `Sheets()`, it assumes you are looking for the index, as in the 2000th sheet not Sheet 2000.

Change it to

```
Sheets(cstr(i)).Select
```

That being said, you really should work through your code and remove the `.select` by referencing the cells directly.  A good resource is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  It will greatly speed up and help ensure fewer errors.

So your For loop would be as such

```
For i = 2000 To 2002              ' for each of the years in turn
    With Sheets(CStr(i))
        .Range(.Range("A17"), .Range("A17").End(xlDown).End(xlToLeft)).Copy
    End With
    With Worksheets("Combined_data")
        y = .UsedRange.Rows.Count        'count how many rows of worksheet "AllData_Raw" have been used so far.
        .Cells(y + 1, 1).Paste
    End With
Next i
```